# не могу вывести корень уравнения, используя метод половинного деления

Tags: c, математика, численные-методы

Возможно я где-то туплю. Но на данный момент я не понимаю...Решаю эту задачу уже третий час.  Моя программа видит только одно: интервал. Не корень.
Задача: Написать программу которая находит решение уравнения N * x + А = 0 методом половинного деления. N - Ваш порядковый номер в журнале, а - Ваш возраст (полных лет). Решение находится в интервале [-100..100].
N == 11, а А - 19.
Метод половинного деления: Методом половинного деления можно находить корни уравнений вида: fx=0 . Корень должен располагаться в некотором интервале ab . Идея метода в следующем - интервал делят пополам, вычисляют значения функции в средней точке и на концах и для дальнейшего поиска корня (уточнения) оставляют тот интервал на границах которого функция меняет знак. Понятно, что корень на этом интервале должен быть один иначе будет найдет только дин из корней. Процесс продолжается до тех пор, пока длина интервал не станет меньше заданной точности. Корень принадлежит этому интервалу, а поэтому может считаться найденным с заданной точностью.

Мой код. Пожалуйста, пишите на примере, если увидите ошибку. Мне так легче.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double F(double x) { //объявление полинома (многочленов)
    double equation;
    equation = 11*x-19;
    return equation;
    
}
int main() {
    double a = -100, b= 100,eps = 0.0001; //,x;
    double result;
    //x = findRoot(a, b, eps); 
    printf("Interval from %f to %f", a, b); 
    if(F(a)*F(b)>0) {
        printf("Wrong interval...");
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
  

double findRoot(double a, double b, double eps) {
    //a == -100; b == 100; eps == 0.0001 (крайнее значение, приближенное к нулю)
    double c; //туда поместим полусумму a и b
    //while ((b-a)/2 > eps) {
    double x;
    c = (a+b)/2;//0
    if (b-a<eps) {
        return c;
    }
    if (F(a)*F(b)>0) {
        return c;
    }
    if (c==0) {
        return c;
    }
    if (F(a)*F(b)<=0) {
        return findRoot(a, c/2, eps);
    }
    else {
        return findRoot(c/2, b, eps);
    }
    x = findRoot(a, b, eps); 
    printf("The root is: %f", x);
            

  
}
```

Буду безумно благодарить за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откровенно говоря, копаться в вашей рекурсивной реализации не очень хочется. Может, вам поможет такая реализация?

```
double binEq(double left, double right, double eps, double (*f)(double))
{
    double x = left;

    if (left > right)
    {
        double t = left;
        left = right;
        right = t;
    }

    double fl = f(left), fr = f(right);

    if (fl*fr > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Wrong range in binEq\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ( right - left > eps )
    {
        x = (left + right)/2.0;
        if (fl * f(x) < 0)
            right = x;
        else
            left = x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Ну, а полное решение вашей задачи - [здесь](https://ideone.com/FQxzYs).

Comment: честно говоря, спасибо...вы выручили!